# What is the name of this tree type?

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

A few years back I used a type of binary tree where each node did not keep a pointer to the child nodes, but instead had a pointer to the next node in a depth first search. It also had a node pointer for skipping all child nodes and going directly to next branch.

It was a tree I came up with myself, but I seem to recall later finding it somewhere else in the literature, so I believe it does have a name... but what is it?

[image]

The drawing shows a binary tree in black, but the black pointers are not explicitly stored. Only the green and red pointers actually exist in the node. To travel the full tree you follow the green pointers one by one. If you want to skip a branch, you follow the red pointer. When you get to an "end of the tree" identifier pointer, you are done.

The point is that even a higher order tree (oct tree for example) can get by with only two pointers per node and you can traverse it without needing a stack. Building it is a bit more complex, though.